# Is it possible to use the Google Drive API with Spreadsheet API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to tie Spreadsheets API in with Drive API? By which I mean, if I have a file ID from Google Drive can I then switch to the Spreadsheets API using the same ID and the same oAuth credentials?

I am using php and there is precious little resources especialy for the spreadsheet api - I'm suprised there's so little around.

Comment: there is also google-apps-script it has a spreadsheet api and has more features than "google-spreadsheet-api".

Comment: Thing is I am working from within an existing web app that I want to update a google spreadsheet from. Perhaps it might be worth looking at doing the other way around?

Answer (score 3):

You additionally need to grant permission for user for the following scope:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
```

The resources IDs are identical on both APIs. My spreadsheet file on Drive, identified with `0AifSjdPVs9MZdE10eXZTVHVneW9aYjJGVFMxV0VYUEE` is accessible on Spreadsheets API with the same ID:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/0AifSjdPVs9MZdE10eXZTVHVneW9aYjJGVFMxV0VYUEE

Note: I made the spreadsheet publicly readable, you can try out Spreadsheets API backends with this file.

Comment: Ah, fantastic thank you. How about when I need to access/edit a private doc that I have the ID for via Drive. How to I use the Spreadsheet API with an oauth access token?

Comment: @koorb, you can use the existing access token to authenticate your requests. Add a 'Authorization: Bearer [your_existing_access_token]' header to your Spreadsheets API request and it should be working fine.

Comment: Ace. Can I work with the Google Spreadsheet API using the google-api-php-client? Like make the requests with Google_REST or something?

Comment: @koorb, no you can't. Spreadsheets API is a GData API -- an ancient protocol once used by all Google APIs. They have a client library but I don't think it's maintained anymore due to the deprecation: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib#gdata-installation

Comment: Ok, do you think the Spreadsheets API will be updated to working within the Drive API?

Comment: Sorry I'm still having a problem, I added `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` to the scope but I'm getting `Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope`

Comment: @koorb, did you retrieve a new access token? This error happens when you're using an access token that is not authorized for the resource's scope.

Comment: I deleted all my stored refresh tokens etc. and went through the entire auth again, it told me the app would have access to spreadsheets, but still get this =/

Comment: @koorb, I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Could you verify your token as explained on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatingtoken ?

Comment: For the scope I have, maybe add them all to see if you can get it to work. (From DrEdit google drive example):        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
       
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I came up with:

1. Get both the google-api-php-client library AND the Zend GData
   library (Zend Framework 1.2, with dependencies).
2. Use the Google API 
   Google_Oauth2Service class to handle login and authentication.  Be
   sure that your "scopes" includes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`  AND 
   `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` .
3. Once the oauth2 handshake is finished (the details of which you can find documentation for), you have a token, which is a json-encoded string.  Turn this into a PHP object: `$tok = json_decode([token string])`
4. And here's the magic: just give the access piece of the token to the Zend library

$authsub = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($tok->access_token);
$spreadsheet_service = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($authsub);

Now you can use your spreadsheet service as documented in the Zend library.  Works great.